# Fill in empty values with the last non-empty in vector

Tags: r, vector

I would like to fill in the missing values (not `NA`, just `''`!) in a vector with the value before it. For example, if I have a vector defined as

```
vec <- c('Titanic', '', '', '', 'Donnie Darko', '', '', 'Twin Peaks', 
         'American Hustle', '')
```

my output vector would be

```
'Titanic', 'Titanic', 'Titanic', 'Titanic', 'Donnie Darko', 'Donnie Darko', 
'Donnie Darko', 'Twin Peaks', 'American Hustle', 'American Hustle'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The easy way would be a for loop. That is what I always end up doing, but there is probably something cleverer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a two-liner with `nzchar` and subsetting that should be quite efficient.

```
# get logical vector of elements with non-empty character elements
notMissings <- nzchar(movies)
# fill in missing values
movies[notMissings][cumsum(notMissings)]
 [1] "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"        
 [5] "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko"    "Twin Peaks"     
 [9] "American Hustle" "American Hustle"
```

---

Here is a second method using `rle`.

```
# get run length encodings
temp <- rle(movies)
# get missing values    
missings <- nchar(temp$values) == 0
# fill in missing values
temp$values[missings] <- temp$values[which(missings) - 1]

# expand
inverse.rle(temp)
 [1] "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"        
 [5] "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko"    "Twin Peaks"     
 [9] "American Hustle" "American Hustle"
```

Note that this second method will throw an error if the first element is the empty character, ''.

**data**

```
movies <- c('Titanic', '', '', '', 'Donnie Darko', '', '', 'Twin Peaks',
            'American Hustle', '')
```

Comment: Great answer, I love that you provided two methods for going about this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Reduce` in base R where `vec` is your vector:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(y=="", x, y), vec, accumulate=TRUE)

#[1] "Titanic"       "Titanic"       "Titanic"       "Titanic"         #"Donnie Darko"   
#[6] "Donnie Darko"  "Donnie Darko"  "Twin Peaks"    "American Hustle" #"American Hustle"
```

Comment: That is a neat use of `Reduce`.

Comment: This works great too, clever use of `Reduce`! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `na.locf` from `zoo` :

```
library(zoo)
vec <- c('Titanic', '', '', '', 'Donnie Darko', '', '', 'Twin Peaks', 'American Hustle', '')
vec[which(vec == "")] <- NA
na.locf(vec)

#  [1] "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic" "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko" 
#  [7] "Donnie Darko"    "Twin Peaks"      "American Hustle" "American Hustle"
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer!

Comment: I also went for it but this will cause problems in presence of `NA`s in vector.

Comment: Added a `which()` to avoid problems with NAs

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
unlist(tapply(movies, cumsum(movies !=""), FUN = 
      function(x) rep(x[1], length(x))), use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Titanic"         "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko"    "Donnie Darko"    "Twin Peaks"     
#[9] "American Hustle" "American Hustle"
```

#### data

```
movies <- c('Titanic', '', '', '', 'Donnie Darko', '', '', 'Twin Peaks', 
          'American Hustle', '')
```